# Storybook - How to set preview layout centered for only some components, not for all components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I am building storybook and have following problem.
I want to set layout centered in preview.
I tried

```
export const parameters = {
  layout: 'centered',
};
```

in the `.storybook/preview.js`
But this sets layout centered for all components.
Is there any good way to show in center for only some components?

Comment: As the guy below says... stop setting it globally. and set it per story. Of course setting it globally sets it for all components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Storybook documentation contains a section for [component level layout](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/story-layout#component-layout).

Instead of configuring it globally in the preview, you can add it to the individual story file.

```
// *.stories.js|jsx|ts|tsx

export default {
  // Other config options...

  // Sets the layout parameter component wide.
  parameters: {
    layout: 'centered',
  },
};
```